# Obfuscate a shared maven module?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate a shared maven module.

Let me explain: i have a multi module maven project (a project with many modules). I can obfuscate the server module by simply including "proguard-maven-plugin" plugin in server module pom.xml. I can do the same for my "client" module. The result is a obfuscated server.jar and client.jar. All my dependencies are nicely put in a /lib/ directory.

My client and server use a "shared" module with common code. When i take a peek in the /lib/ directory i see that the shared.jar is not obfuscated (which is likely because proguard-maven-plugin adds it as libaryjar in proguard configuration).

Now i suspect I'm missing something, but how can i obfuscate my shared module when my client/server are obfuscated?

[edit] i cannot include the  proguard-maven-plugin in the shared module pom.xml , cause then i will get a lot of "can't find referenced class" when the server/client is being build/obfuscated, this makes sense cause proguard renames a lot.

[edit] No need for a full example, just a high level overview how this can be solved is enough. I can figure out the rest ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question: the maven plugin does support assembly tags.

Including the shared library in the assembly section and excluding the shared library in the configuration did solve the problem.